# Bulk edit UrbanCode configuration?

Tags: repository, edit, urbancode

I want to do some bulk search/edit operation on the scripts embedded in our UrbanCode components and applications, and possibly on the flowcharts and blueprints. Unfortunately a lot of this is stored in UrbanCode's own repository, where it can only be access through the browser GUI and I can't do things like grep for common patterns across the whole set.

Is there any documented way to check out/check in, or at least download, a copy of an entire UCD environment as text files that I could analyze?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest documented way to get some of the things you are looking for is to export the application and to search through the json file. Component processes with all their steps are included in the application export.